# How to include only items inbetween "

Tags: regex, url

Have a URL below:

```
<a href="https://location.domain/Orion/NetPerfMon/MapView.aspx?Map=43e2fae1-a0eb-4f58-934e-6e6d57cc4e97.OrionMap&amp;Title=Rail%20Fiber">Rail Fibre</a>
```

But I want a regex to only include the URL such as:

```
https://location.domain/Orion/NetPerfMon/MapView.aspx?Map=43e2fae1-a0eb-4f58-934e-6e6d57cc4e97.OrionMap&amp;Title=Rail%20Fiber
```

So I only want the output to include anything inbetween the Quotation marks
" "

This is for my Orion network monitoring server and my regex understanding is shocking.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is likely to work:

```
<a\s+href="\s*(https?[^"]+)\s*".*?>.*?<\/a>
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OV5dHn/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OV5dHn/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="\K[^"]+
```

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oUQOqt/1)

`\K` - means: in the march, the regex will return a match just from here.

`[^"]` - means: Every character except then `"`.